Raster Alignment producing invalid layers (QGIS 2.18.28)
I am trying to align raster layers (reference layer is "modelo") because I need matching geometries in order to use them as input on a plugin (MOLUSCE), which only exists in QGIS 2.
I tried aligning them on QGIS 3 which worked.But when opening those new (aligned/resampled) layers on QGIS 2, the resampled layers only have NA values, and when trying to visualize layer properties, a "bad allocation" warning comes up and I cannot open layer properties. So I tried aligning them on QGIS 2 and the result was the same.
The only difference was when unticking the "redimension input according to cell size" option,

which in turn produced a valid layer (can access its properties) but with nonsense values.
The process worked normally with 2 layers (agua and dist_to_pr), producing valid and correctly valued layers. But not with the others.
Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

apparently QGIS2 does not accept layers that have/had nodata values when aligned
